# Pandas: sort multiple columns based on some rules for possible values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([ ['X', 1],
                    ['a', 3],        
                    ['b', 4],
                    ['Y', 1],
                    ['Y', 4] ],
                    columns=['col1', 'col2' ]
                   )

df
  col1 col2
0    X   1
1    a   3
2    b   4
3    Y   1
4    Y   4
```

I would like to create a sorting rule that first sorts by col2, and then sorts by col1 based on a rule such that X should come first, then Y, and the rest can be alphabetical. None of the values are gauranteed to be in the dataframe, but if they are, I would like to sort as described. Desired result would be:

```
df
  col1 col3
0    X   1
1    Y   1
2    a   3
3    Y   4
4    b   4
```

I know I can sort by a special order if I know all the values in the column, using Categorical like so:

```
df.col1=pd.Categorical(df.col1,['X','Y','a', 'b'])
df.sort_values(['col2','col1'])
```

But I don't know what values will be present in col1. Was considering making a list in python from the col1 values, and sorting that list using some logic and then passing that sorted list to Categorical, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way perhaps just using pandas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper key

```
df['helpkey']=np.where(df.col1.isin(['X','Y']),0,1)
df.sort_values(['col2','helpkey','col1'])
Out[410]: 
  col1  col2  helpkey
0    X     1        0
3    Y     1        0
1    a     3        1
4    Y     4        0
2    b     4        1
```

Then you can using `drop('helperkey',1)` to drop the helper column